# How to Social Share individual pieces of content - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, facebook-share, socialshare

this is a rather generic question I know but i was hoping someone could point me in the correct direction.

Im building a Wordpress site, the site has a middle content section made up of 3 columns - 3 rows so total 9 panels.

I would like to include social share buttons in these columns, I am aware that there are many social sharing plugings for wordpress however when the user clicks on the share button I would like only the information in this column to be shared. E.g a predefined picture and text. Each columns data will be different they all have an image and text.

How can i choose what information to share when the user clicks the share button instead of sharing the whole page like must plugins?

SO for each content that is going to be shared, i can say use this image and use this text. Is this possible?

Thanks

Any guidance would be great.

Comment: I am also researching on similar functionality. Do post if you find any solution for it. I will update as well if find any thing that suffice this requirement.

Comment: will do....canbt find anything at the moment